# What is the significance of Protocol in elixir?

Tags: elixir

Having used the term Protocol with network (http, ftp etc), I am confused with its usage in Elixir.  For e.g. there are references to Enum module and Enumerable Protocol.  Elixir documentation says `Protocols are a mechanism to achieve polymorphism in Elixir`.

Aren't they just a module with a set of methods/functions? Are there any distinctions?

Comment: The use of Protocol in Elixir is similar to the way Protocol is generally defined in languages such as Objective C. In OO languages it means a set of methods that you promise to implement.

Comment: This actually goes way back to Smalltalk (1980). For all practical purposes, think of it as an API, Interface, ... indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of protocol as of interface in Java / abstract class in Python (in fact, java interfaces and specifically python abstract classes are more to `@behaviour`, but anyway.)

```
defprotocol Sound do
  def make_sound(data)
end

defmodule Dog do
  defstruct name: "Donny"
end

defimpl Sound, for: Dog do
  def make_sound(data) do
    "#{data.name} barks “woof”"
  end
end

defmodule Cat do
  defstruct name: "Hilly"
end

defimpl Sound, for: Cat do
  def make_sound(data) do
    "#{data.name} murrs “meow”"
  end
end
```

and there in the code:

```
%Dog{} |> Sound.make_sound
#⇒ "Donny barks “woof”"
```

or:

```
pet = .... # complicated code loading a struct
pet |> Sound.make_sound # here we don’t care what pet we have
```

---

This mechanism is used in string interpolation:

```
"#{5}"
```

The above works because `Integer` has the implementation of `String.Chars`. The implementation just calls

```
WHATEVER_IN_#{} |> String.Chars.to_string
```

to get a binary. For instance. for aforementioned `Dog` module we might implement `String.Chars`:

```
defimpl String.Chars, for: Dog do
  def to_string(term) do
    "#{term.name} barks “woof”"
  end
end
```

Now one might interpolate dogs:

```
"#{%Dog{}}"
#⇒ "Donny barks “woof”"
```

Comment: It is helpful to dig into what defimpl actually does: It creates the module String.Chars.Dog with function to_string. If you look in _build/test/protocol/ebin, you'll see all the modules that actually get created.

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog yes, it’s true, but I personally find this being an implementation detail, that is not strictly required to understand _the significance_ of protocols.

Comment: Perhaps, but my experience is that there is a lot of unnecessary mystery around Protocols for Elixir beginners. Knowing the implementation details helps unwind the mystery.